# HTTP requests from WebExtensions options page not working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, wikipedia-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a Firefox browser extension. Some HTTP requests sent from the options tab never return. This hello world works:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", true);
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log(req.response);
});
req.send(null);
```

But, for example, this Wikipedia API endpoint doesn't return the expected response:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_cognitive_biases&format=json&prop=links&pllimit=10", true);
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log(req.response);
});
req.send(null);
```

How do I make this second request work from the options tab?

In case this is relevant, I set this in the *manifest.json* page in order to get the options page to load in its own tab:

```json
"options_ui": {
  "open_in_tab": true
}
```

Comment: `does not work` - have you looked in the developer tools console and network tabs for any clue to this mystery?

Comment: Please provide a *complete* [MCVE].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: Have you tried this in other contexts to verify that the issue is that it is being done from an options page?

Comment: I understand the value of a reproduceable example, but I'm not sure how you can possibly reproduce this problem without having a firefox extension environment already running on your computer :(

Comment: And yes. I opened a new tab and copy/pasted the exact same code to make the HTTP request and it worked fine.

Comment: Hm, interesting. So the example I gave of an HTTP request that doesn't work in fact returns a status of 200, but the response is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data", which is why it didn't work when I tried to print out the request response.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The HTTP requests didn't work because I need to set this option in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>"
]
```